# Can tablets containing iron or high fibre food trigger anxiety and hypermetabolism?

Tags: gastroenterology, diagnostics, diagnosis

Is there any well-understood way or any info, in the medical literature, regarding the possibility of iron tablets and high fibre foods triggering anxiety, panic attacks and hypermetabolism characterized by tachycardia, , insomnia, tremors, weight loss, hypermotility coupled with gastritis?

The only thing I could think of is through them triggering some form of dormant non invasive amoebic colitis resulting from a chronic GI candida infection or triggering some kind of auto immune reaction. But I still cannot understand the mechanism of this leading to the above mentioned symptoms.

What could be the possible cause and mechanism?

---

**Edit: Any info you have on this, even in the form of comment is appreciated.**

Comment: Any info you have on this, even in the form of comment is appreciated.

Comment: Well, for one, what do iron tablets have to do with fiber? Do you mean do the two in combination cause all those things, or do you mean can either one alone cause them? It's hard to imagine that either of them would cause any of the non-GI issues you listed, and I don't understand why you're combining them.

Comment: @CareyGregory Both high fiber food and Iron and multimineral tablets can trigger colitis. So either of them can cause it.

Comment: @CareyGregory The Crohn's and Colitis Foundation considers foods rich in insoluble fiber a potential trigger for UC. But a 2020 study found that a low fat, high fiber diet improved quality of life for people with mild UC or UC in remission   https://www.healthline.com/health/ulcerative-colitis/ulcerative-colitis-and-fiber#:~:text=The%20Crohn's%20and%20Colitis%20Foundation,UC%20or%20UC%20in%20remission.

Comment: @CareyGregory Studies show iron supplements can worsen inflammation in the digestive tract. This makes Crohn's disease and ulcerative colitis symptoms worse. Iron supplements can cause digestive side effects, including cramping, nausea, diarrhea, and constipation, even if you're in remission https://www.healthline.com/health/anemia/ulcerative-colitis-crohns-anemia-link#:~:text=Studies%20show%20iron%20supplements%20can,if%20you're%20in%20remission.

Comment: But your question doesn't even mention UC. It asks about symptoms unrelated to UC. Anyway, I wasn't asking you to explain. I was suggesting that you could [edit] your question to improve it and improve the chances of getting a good answer. Telling me things in comments doesn't help.

Comment: More plausible is that the tablets are contaminated with something else, if they had anything to do with the symptoms. We can't do a toxicology analysis over the internet, so...

Comment: Iron OD looks nothing like that; basically it causes blood vomiting and anal bleeding too. @CareyGregory: no idea why this Q wasn't closed, it's basically asking for a diagnosis.

Comment: @Fizz Hmmm... I don't see any close votes. I guess yours didn't "take?" ;)

Comment: @CareyGregory: can't VTC while the bounty is up. SE rules.

Comment: @CareyGregory yes it's indicated in flaring and worsening up of colitis. Soy question is, is there any literature associating it with other form of colitis, like amoebic colitis and especially non invasive amoebic infection where typical symptoms like diarrhea isn't present.

Comment: @Fizz isn't questions explorimg etiology and diagnostics not allowed here? There's a tag for diagnostics.

Comment: @Fizz ignore the toxicology hypothesis, the question is trying to see if iron and high fiber foods can trigger other forms of colitis by irritating the gut line and causing an immune response etc. Is there any medical literature on this.

Comment: @MrGreenGold What Fizz was suggesting was that your question appears to be a request for a personal diagnosis for you or someone else.

Comment: @CareyGregory this question is asked from research point of view. It's asking for a mechanism, even if known wouldn't be of use to treat anyone.

Comment: @MrGreenGold It's such a specific list of symptoms, and unusual ones at that. We get a **lot** of medical advice questions here, often disguised as research questions, so Fizz questioning it is understandable.

Comment: @CareyGregory yes makes sense

Answer (score 1):

Since (given the comments) it seems the question is about iron in ulcerative colitis (UC)... Iron doesn't *cause* (ulcerative) colitis *per se*; it's a recommended supplement in people with UC [because](https://www.healthline.com/health/anemia/ulcerative-colitis-crohns-anemia-link) they often have anemia (iron deficiency) as a result of UC, which causes poor iron absorption in the digestive tract.

On the other hand, oral supplementation with iron may not be well tolerated in UC. Based on animal models, it might [worsen UC symptoms](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC6181268/) especially during an UC episode/flare-up. If that's the case, alternative route of iron administration, such as IV [is suggested](https://www.healthline.com/health/anemia/ulcerative-colitis-crohns-anemia-link#treatment).

However, I'm not convinced that most of the symptoms you've listed are related to UC. Tachycardia might be related be [via hypomagnesemia](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/6799255/), i.e. magnesium deficiency, which is also sometimes present in UC. No way to know without laboratory blood tests, which of course we can't do over the internet.

As for the mental health aspects, the causality relation with UC is [even more complicated](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4376063/); UC might actually be worsened by anxiety, rather than the other way around, or stress in general might exacerbate both. And panic attacks [are themselves](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3547429/) related to tachycardia, even in patients without UC.